# execute asynccallback first

Tags: gwt, onclick

I have this code:

```
    searchButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

            statusLabel.setText("Searching...");

            final String query = searchField.getText();
            RootPanel.get("flickr").clear();
            AsyncCallback<Flickr> ac=new AsyncCallback<Flickr>(){

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Flickr result) {

                    for(Photo p:result.getPhotos().getPhoto())
                    {
                        flck.add(p);
                    }
                    statusLabel.setText("");
                }
            };

            mashupService.getFlickrPhotos(query, ac);

            if(!flck.isEmpty())
            {
                for(int i=0;i<flck.size();i++)
                {
                    RootPanel.get("flickr").add(new HTML("<img  src='http://farm"+flck.get(i).getFarm()+".staticflickr.com/"+flck.get(i).getServer()+"/"+flck.get(i).getId()+"_"+flck.get(i).getSecret()+".jpg'/><br/>"));

                }
            }

            }
    });
```

I want execute first onSuccess (have flick.add)... but it executes after of if(!flck.isEmpty)... and I need have flck with data but I can't...

When I press secont time the same button, flck have data of first onClick...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the code inside the `onSuccess()` method that is depended on the result of `AsyncCallback`.

---

It's clear from the name that `AsyncCallback` is just like a `AJAX request` that talks to server `asynchronously` means the execution of code is not sequential.

Just move `if(!flck.isEmpty)...` inside `onSuccess()` method.

Comment: Thank you I did and work it, I was crazy... but now i have to put that photos on a map... I'm going to put that code on last "onSuccess"